# What is the purpose of adding header to a http post/get in java?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers

Can please give me a link or an explanantion that would make me understand the purpouse of http header and cookies that are sent with http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out [click here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) it contains a decent explaination on this topic

**The purpose of sending headers with http post/get request is that it tells the reciever or sender that what type of information is sent or recieved.**

and about cookies read this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon. Please include actual information, using the link as an additional resource. Two upvotes on a link-only answer is baffling.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
Practically in header you can add auth information like login/password to site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [W3 specification on  session management](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt),which covers all the topics related to the HTTP protocol.

HTTP State Management Mechanism  documentation.

> The designers' paradigm for
>      sessions created by the exchange of cookies
>
> HTTP
>      allows an open-ended set of methods and headers that indicate the
>      purpose of a request

Answer (score 0):

Just use wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Main idea of headers its to mark each packet with information that helps to sender and receiver understand what they need to do with this packet.

If you need more detailed info about that just read any book about TCP/IP or about HTTP protocol.